Long dictionary/map key vs shorter key + equality check for an auth cache
I'm implementing an API key based authentication scheme and I'm caching valid API key entries (hash, scope etc.) in a memory cache. For the cache key, I had been using the first 8 characters of the base 64 representation of the key hash. I did this because there are 64^8 (281,474,976,710,656) possible keys, so I thought that would be more than enough.
Then when a key arrived, I hashed it, encoded it in base64, grabbed the first 8 characters then pulled the auth details from the cache and returned it to the API logic.
But considering it further, I significantly reduce collision resistance by doing this. It still has a large amount of collision resistance, but haven't I just reduced key entropy to 32 bit instead of 128 bit? So an attacker only has to match the first 32 bits of the key to pass.
I have a couple of options:

Leave it as it is, but do an equality check between the full length keys before returning the matching auth entry. (If it doesn't match, log the attempt and fail the auth request)

Use the full length hash for the cache key.


Approach 1 seems to be a bit awkward, if I'm doing an equality check straight after, the key might as well be better. Approach 2 seems better.
I expect 128bit hashing for the cache key is probably slightly slower than 32 bit hashing + an equality check. But I suspect it's neither here nor there.
Is there any other advantage to either approach (or a different approach I haven't considered)?

"But I suspect it's neither here nor there." This is the important thing. Unless you have shown via profiling or similar this check is actually significant, just do the simple thing and use 128 bit keys.

You'd have to be very hard up for memory these days until trading a small number of bytes in RAM for added code complexity makes any sense at all.

if you have  no collision risk on the shorter key. why do you have a long api key at all? This seems like a recipe for security holes

Remember that attacker does not have to match a paticular key. They just need to match any key from the large pool of your active users.

@KilianFoth I was coming to a similar conclusion myself when looking at the code.

@Ewan the API keys are randomly generated 128 bit keys, which are SHA256 hashed before being persisted and cached. The 32 bit key was intended just to be a unique key for the cache store. So 32 bits was likely to be enough to prevent accidental key collisions, but it is possibly not enough against brute force attacks, which is why we opted for 128 bit API keys.

@Basilevs that's true. I think just using the full 128bit hash as the cache key is the way to go.

Why would you generate random key and then hash it? And then base64? And finally truncation? That's weird and unnecessary on its own. Just use random key. Secondly, just use more bits. It hardly costs anything but makes the process significantly more secure.

Hashing and base64 encoding on top of randomness doesn't bring anything useful. You may want to base64 encode it if you want to send it as text. But that has nothing to do with security. So, randomly generate, I don't know, 33 bytes, because why not? And then base64 encode it, and you're done: that's your key.

@freakish I'm not doing anything unusual. I'm generating a 128 bit API key for the client, which is hexadecimal encoded for easy entry into their integrations. This isn't stored on the server for obvious security reasons. I hash it before recording it and compare the API key against the hash. The hash is created as a byte array, but .NET memory cache needs a string key, hence the base64 encoding.

@freakish I'm not really sure what made you think I was equating base 64 encoding with security? I just wanted a unique key for the cache.

@KyoheiKaneko again: if the key is randomly generated, then hashing is completely unneeded and irrelevant. Also, once you hexencode, once base64 encode, make up your mind.

@freakish I am hashing to avoid storing a plain text key in the server database and cache. Why is that uneeded? Otherwise, if someone managed to dump the DB they would have every user's API key. It's standard practice not to store password plain text, why is it any different for API keys? If I generate an API key (or so-called app password) for Gmail, for example, it shows me the password at the time of creation and never again afterwards. Logically, this is because they hash it and don't store the original.

@freakish Your argument about "making up my mind" about hex encoding vs base64 is over the top. Again, the hex encoding is for the string key to provide the user so they don't need to match case when entering a long key into a UI. But once I hash the key I have it in bytes, not a string (again hashing it for the reasons above). So, I can choose however I want to get a string key for the cache key. Base64 is shorter than hex, and I have no reason to use hex internally. "For consistency" would be arbitrary and uneeded. It's an internal implementation detail, base 64 is the better choice.

Avoid Premature Optimization
This is premature optimization. You don't know if using 128 bits is slow or fast. You're complicating a simple operation and spending a lot of time thinking about a part of the code that might or might not be slow. Only optimize once you know it is a bottleneck of some kind and have measured it (YAGNI).
Also keep in mind, it's not just your attacker that has to match the first 32 bits. You'll fully overwrite a valid API key with another valid API key if they happen to have a collision, leading to some nasty bugs and unhappy customers if you get enough usage on this API. 32 bit hash values have a 1 in 100 Chance of collision at 9292 entries, and a 1 in 10 Chance at 30084, according to This site

Thanks for the answer, particularly the link at the end regarding collision probabilities. I hadn't realised how high a chance there would be of collision with 32 bit keys.

As a side point though, I don't think increasing the number of buckets will reduce a bottleneck caused by a long cache key. If hashing the cache key to look up the correct bucket takes too long, the way to fix it is to use a faster hashing algorithm (or shorter key)

You're right. I remembered that Loadfactor can increase the speed without considering it's just the actual lookup speed. I'll edit my answer to remove that.
